# Mostrar un decimal en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

mi problema es el siguiente
traigo un valor desde mi gridview a sql y me tira un error de conversion ( Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric )
el problema que cuando lo trae de mi gridview lo trae con una coma 
(hablando de la columna de montoNeto)

dejo mi query

```
select TransaccionId, CodigoCuenta, CuentaDescripcion, ID_Secundaria,

ID_CTA_Secundaria, Nombre_Secundaria,

Fecha_Creacion, TipoComprobante, CodigoComprobante, JornalDescripcion,

MontoNeto, Fecha_Efectiva,

LineaDescripcion, Movimiento.Descripcion, UserId, FechaCargaSistema,

nombreApellido_usuario,

nombre_cliente

from Mayorizacion3

where CodigoCuenta = '1010304010' and Fecha_Creacion >= '01/10/2018'

and Fecha_Creacion <= '01/12/2018' and CodigoComprobante='AD' and Clientes.id_cliente='1' and MontoNeto='554,17'
```

alguna idea??
desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Donde usas el valor del textbox?

Comment: perdon perdon! lo tomo de una gridview los valores, lo redacte mal

Comment: pero que campo exactamente es el que te da problemas?

Comment: el de monto neto (tipo decimal), ya que lo trae con una coma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrás entonces que usar la funcion REPLACE para hacer que esa "," que viene con tu textBox se convierta en "." para la parte decimal. ¿Entiendo que el campo es el que viene en MontoNeto? De no ser asi, coloca

> REPLACE(de_donde_venga_el_dato,",",".")

```sql
select TransaccionId
       ,CodigoCuenta
       ,CuentaDescripcion 
       ,ID_Secundaria
       ,ID_CTA_Secundaria
       ,Nombre_Secundaria
       ,Fecha_Creacion
       ,TipoComprobante
       ,CodigoComprobante
       ,JornalDescripcion
       ,REPLACE(MontoNeto,",",".") AS MontoNeto
       ,Fecha_Efectiva
       ,LineaDescripcion
       ,Movimiento.Descripcion
       ,UserId
       ,FechaCargaSistema
       ,nombreApellido_usuario
       ,nombre_cliente
from Mayorizacion3
where CodigoCuenta = '1010304010' and Fecha_Creacion >= '01/10/2018'and 
      Fecha_Creacion <= '01/12/2018' and CodigoComprobante='AD' and 
      Clientes.id_cliente='1' and MontoNeto='554,17'
```

Comment: el error me lo tira aca en el where la parte and MontoNeto='554,17'  . Por ejemplo cuando cambio la , por el punto  Me lo toma los mas bien, el tema es ahi

Comment: Y si la condición del where la has metido hardcode, que problema tienes en cambiar esa "," por un "."?

Comment: me tira esto Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a numeric. como hardcore? te refereris al replace en el select ?

Comment: Claro hombre, MontoNeto es un tipo numérico, y donde tu estas filtrando en el WHERE lo estas metiendo entre comillas, a no ser que una de dos, las quites, o hagas un CAST seguira dandote ese error.